# How to force control ignore any gui events in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events, silverlight-4.0, controls, transparency

I have a simple page with canvas control.
Inside canvas I have some SL controls like buttons, textboxes etc. 
Also I cover the controls by semi-transparent Image control. So, when I click on some button, the click message doesn't  reach the button, because I click on Image.

Is there a way to say the Image that it must not handle any gui events ?

p.s I use SL4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `IsHitTestVisible="False"` to your image.